# Отсутствует функция uic в pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

[image: Устанавливал PyQt5 в виртуальное окружение и никак не получается подгрузить модуль uic]

Устанавливал PyQt5 в виртуальное окружение и никак не получается подгрузить модуль uic, так же установлен pyqt5-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> никак не получается подгрузить модуль uic

Модуль `uic` у вас импортирован из `PyQt5` без ошибок, и проблема не в этом.

Вместо `PyQt5.uic.loadUi` напишите `uic.loadUi`.

Ваша запись должна выглядеть так:

```
uic.loadUi("chat.ui", self)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!